# Cannot import class for another modle into main 'app' module

Tags: android, kotlin

I was developing some multimodule app, and I'm not beeing able to configure properly, due to the class I want to use in app module still doesn't found.

I have this in my build.gradle for my app module:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    namespace 'es.paytef.hioposconnector'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "es.paytef.hioposconnector"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'

    // Librerías agregadas
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.7.20"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    implementation("javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0-2")

    // retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1"

    // hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.40"
    //Singleton and Inject annotation
    implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    implementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.40"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha03"

    //hilt libraries for custom Component.
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.40"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.40"

    //dev_resource
    implementation project(path: ':dev_resources')
}
```

I have this as dev_resources build.gradle module:

```
group 'org.openapitools'
version '1.0.0'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.21'
    ext.retrofitVersion = '2.9.0'

    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.10.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:$retrofitVersion"
    testImplementation "io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.4.2"
}
```

And this as settings.gradle in my project:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "HioPos Connector"
include ':app'
include ':dev_resources'
```

Things I tried:

- Add library pluging to dev_resource module.

So what Am I missing??

Comment: Actually all looks fine. Is class public, not internal? If you can upload minimal version to git, I will try to help you

Comment: I cannot do that due to company reason, but thanks for the help !